# React Components name changes on staging server

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am building a Meteor app with react and deployed to a staging server. For some reason, react acts weirdly. In the react dev tool, all my components name has been changed to **t**.

*This is a screenshot from my localhost* 
[image: Localhost Screenshot]

*This is a screenshot from my staging server*
[image: Production Screenshot]

I also get an error wherever I try to use `this.setState()`

I don't know what information is relevant. I think it should be my server environment so I will state those.

- **OS**: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- **Meteor version**: 1.3
- **Node Version**: v0.10.43
- **Npm Verison**: 2.14.22

Don't know if this is relevant but when I run `npm install` in my `bundle/programs/server` folder I get this warning

```
    npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js
```

Comment: I believe it's due to code minification (and identifiers mangling).

Comment: So is this supposed to happen? I have a couple of projects with older meteor where this does not happen and everything works fine

Comment: I have the same behaviour in a non-meteor-based app. So I believe it's something else that has changed. Like: react version.

Comment: ohh, okay then, probably something else that is breaking my `this.setState()` everywhere

Comment: Btw, it's the same on http://instagram.com

Comment: I see they have a mixture of **r**, **n**, **i**, but I went a little deeper and I saw a `ScrollWatchedComponent` & `ResponsiveBlock`

Comment: Production build performs code minification. You can try it on localhost by running `meteor run --production`.

Comment: verified. Thanks guys